# awk - printing fixed length line having special character

Tags: awk

I am using the below command to extract specific lines from a fixed length file.
The length line for each line is 748

```
awk 'substr($0,8,2)=="04"' test.dat > output.dat
```

Let's say the test.dat had 100 lines. In the output file I see some of the lines are way less than 748 characters.

Is it because the awk is trucating the line when handling special chanracters? If so is there way we can avoid it?

From the Answers below I understand that POSIX awk will not hable null and other special charecters. Is there a another option with sed or grep can do this for me?

Comment: The only special character that should cause any problems would be a newline.  Any newlines embedded within your 748-character long records?

Comment: Yes the last character is a newline

Comment: I mean, when you see a line that's less than the expected 748 characters, is it because there is a newline in the middle of the record (where it is cut off)?

Comment: I dont think thee will be a newline but we are seeing many /0 in the data file..

Comment: I created a file with an embedded `\0` in the line and plain awk truncated the record there, just as you're seeing. However, when I tried with __gawk__, it printed the entire line. If you have access to gawk, maybe try seeing if that works better for you.

Comment: And Special characters like  \x0

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have gawk

Comment: @manchand then you are out of luck because other awks cannot handle null characters in a file since they are for plain text only.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking how to do something in a POSIX awk that simply cannot be done in a POSIX awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coverting the null into space was not an issue for me, So I used the below command to get the data I needed.

perl -pe 's/\000/ /g'  Inputfile| awk 'substr($0,64,2)=="04"' > Outputfile